# Can't commit from git plugin in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I try to commit my project from within IntelliJ IDEA, it's showing an error message like
this:

> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
>
> error: Sample2/.idea/vcs.xml: failed to insert into database
>
> error: unable to index file Sample2/.idea/vcs.xml
>
> fatal: updating files failed

I am working in Ubuntu 10.10 and I logged in as a user with admin permissions.
Repository for git is my project folder itself which is in my local system.
Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: Does commit work from the command line git?

Comment: it is working from command line git with the support of 'sudo' only .but how i can commit via that plugin???

Answer (score 2):

Looks like permissions issue of your local git clone. Try `chown -R user:user /project/directory` (where user is your account name) to ensure that IDEA running under non-root account has write permissions in the project directory including .git subdirectory.